# Finding a username with only their Discord ID with Discord.js

Tags: typescript, sqlite, discord.js

I am making a leader board bot and have realized that it pings users too much when called, I wanted to only display their current username.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
   let place = i + 1;
   if(i < board.length){
       let username = board[i].id;
       if(board[i].id === user){
           onBoard = true;
       }
       leader += `*${place}*.  <@${username}>  score: **${board[i].score}**\n`;
   }
}
```

So every time we post the top 10 users they all get pinged so instead I want to just post their username, with the consideration that I have only saved their Discord ID with some SQLite.

Comment: Is "username" an id?

Comment: yes, its pulled from the database we have

Answer (score 1):

You can use `client.users.cache.get("ID")` to get the user and display it's username.

---

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let place = i + 1;

    if (i < board.length) {
        const User = client.users.cache.get(board[i].id);

        if (board[i].id === user) {
            onBoard = true
        };

        leader += `*${place}*. ${User.username} Score: **${board[i].score}**`

        // User.username
        // --> MyUsername

        // User.tag
        // --> MyUsername#0629
    }
};
```